# Careers: give me a place to list my proficiencies and years of experience

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I don't have a formal education so to overcompensate on my traditional resume I have a section at the top that lists out all my proficiencies along with how many years of experience I have with that skill. I have been frequently complimented on this because it gives hiring managers a good overview of my skill set. It would be nice to have a similar feature on Careers. For the skills you could use SO tags.

Answer (score 1):

They may institute that, but [it doesn't seem likely](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001054.html).